# JavaScript Variable Retaining Last Input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a ButtonLink added to a asp:gridview that displays a model pop-up window with a notification message and the text from cell[1] of the row that was clicked.  For 98% of them there is the default standard message, which is the cell[1] value, but for these few caveats I want to display a custom message based off the value in cell[1].

My issue I have with this syntax is that it always shows

> Gi Joe Destory Cobra

regardless of what the actual text for row.cells[1] is.  Can someone assist in a re-write so it will function as I want?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var row;
     function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
         row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
         var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
         if (row.cells[1].innerHTML = "Green Lantern") {
             desc = "Please input villian."
         }
         if (row.cells[1].innerHTML = "Batman") {
             desc = "Stay out of Gotham."
         }
         if (row.cells[1].innerHTML = "Gi Joe") {
             desc = "Destroy Cobra."
         }
         else { desc = row.cells[1].innerHTML; }
         $('#<%=lblText.ClientID %>').text(desc);
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
     }
</script>
```

**EDIT**
I altered my code to this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var row;
     function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
         row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
         var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
         if (row.cells[1].innerHTML == "Green Lantern") {
             desc = "Please input villian."
         }
         if (row.cells[1].innerHTML == "Batman") {
             desc = "Stay out of Gotham."
         }
         if (row.cells[1].innerHTML == "Gi Joe") {
             desc = "Destroy Cobra."
         }
         else { desc = row.cells[1].innerHTML; }
         $('#<%=lblText.ClientID %>').text(desc);
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
     }
</script>
```

But for example if user clicks the ButtonLink for Gi Joe instead of desc displaying Descroy Cobra it displays GI Joe.

Comment: Compare with `===`. Single `=` is used for assigning variables.

Comment: Typo.  You're using `=` instead of `==` (or `===` for type checking as well).  *All* of those `if` conditions are "truthy".

Comment: @David - so change all = to ==

Comment: @BoJackHorseman: When used for *comparison*, yes.  There is, of course, considerably more information on the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: @David - I change syntax to  (row.cells[1].innerHTML = "Gi Joe") {
             desc = "Destroy Cobra."
         } but now it will not display Destroy Cobra it will display the innerHTML

Comment: @BoJackHorseman: You're going to have to be more clear about what you changed.  Can you update the code in the question to reflect the current code?  And specifically what is happening?

Comment: @David - posted edit.  Please let me konw if that helps clarify

Comment: @BoJackHorseman: Interesting.  I don't see how the value of `desc` could ever be `"Gi Joe"` in that code.  Can you use your browser's debugging tools to narrow the problem?  You can place a breakpoint inside this function and see specifically what's happening line by line.  When you step through the function, where specifically does something unexpected first happen?

Comment: @David - my breakpoint is never hit in VS2015.  I have not been succesful at debugging JavaScript from Visual Studio

Comment: @BoJackHorseman: I find that in-browser debugging tends to be more effective for JavaScript.  (Though I suppose the tooling in Visual Studio may have improved, I'm not sure.)  Use the debugging tools that are in your browser.

Comment: If I add an alert(row.cells[1].innerHTML); statement directly below the var rowIndex line I get the correct line returned.  However, none of my if statements return true when using ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure difference between **if condition and else if**

```
     if (row.cells[1].innerHTML == "Green Lantern") {
         desc = "Please input villian."
     }
     else if (row.cells[1].innerHTML == "Batman") {
         desc = "Stay out of Gotham."
     }
     else if (row.cells[1].innerHTML == "Gi Joe") {
         desc = "Destroy Cobra."
     }
     else { desc = row.cells[1].innerHTML; }
```

Comment: Good catch.  In the OP's code if either of the first two `if` blocks are reached, the final `else` would *also* be reached and overwrite the value.